# How do I delete an item in the Finder's toolbar?

Tags: macos, finder

[image]

How do I delete the file link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You delete it by dragging it away from the bar, while holding <kbd>Cmd</kbd>.

The same combination applies to any item in the toolbar as well as the Finder's sidebar.